# Discord.py missing permissions error with permissions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I try to edit the Roles from a Member trough the `member.edit(roles = list_of_roles)` command. For the most Users this works just finde, but for some the I get the Error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` altrough the bot HAS the heighest role on the Server AND admin rights. (No the Role that I try to remove/add is NOT highter or at the same Level as the bot role) Is there anything I might missed? because I dont understand why he cant remove the roles from some members (the members dont have admin rights).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours I found out, you cant remove the booster role. This is why ít doesn't work how it should.